# Does Gordan's Lemma hold in infinite dimensional vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-cone, dual-cone

> **Gordan's Lemma:** Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.  Then exactly one of the following two statements is true:
>
> - There exists $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $Ax > 0$, or
> - There exists nonzero $y \ge 0 \in \mathbb{R}^m$ with $yA = 0$.

Does this statement still hold if $m$ is countably infinite?  If so, does this fact follow easily from the finite-dimensional setting or does it require significant new machinery?

Comment: What does $>$ mean in this context?

Comment: @Mr.Chip: Typically elementwise.

Comment: What do you mean by $m$ being countably infinite? Is there some topology on the resulting space? I would guess that the geometric form of the Hahn Banach theorem is the appropriate tool here.